# Money copy paste on chrome

Tags: google-chrome, browser, desktop-computer, website

Hello i am trying to copy paste a money text from excel to web site textbox here is example

3.165,62 TL on excel
0.00,00 on site

My computer doing that but another my friend computer making it on website 316,56. Do you have ideas what is the problem on my friend's computer

Thank you so much

Comment: In the US `.` is a decimal point instead of a thousands separator. Maybe the website is designed to handle US style numbers? Are both of you using the same language settings on your computers?

Comment: Maybe but my computer doing it perfectly. my friend's computer making it wrong so im trying to figure out is there a problem on my friend's computer or web browser

Comment: The problem could be the language settings. Check to make sure both of you have the same  "Regional Format" setting in Windows.

Comment: Oh my god sir you are a life saver. I think you found the right thing. Yes it can be done with Regional Format settings. Thank you so much

Comment: The problem could be the language settings. Check to make sure both of you have the same "Regional Format" setting in Windows please answer my question with this thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the US . is a decimal point instead of a thousands separator.

Maybe your friend is using a different "Regional Format" setting on their system?

If the other system is Windows, here is how you can change the setting:
[Change the Windows regional settings to modify the appearance of some data types](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/change-the-windows-regional-settings-to-modify-the-appearance-of-some-data-types-edf41006-f6e2-4360-bc1b-30e9e8a54989)

Comment: correct thank you i solved this with your answer